# when does the activated event fire in windows phone 8.1 WINRT apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

I have overridden the OnActivated  event in the app.xaml, but  the handler is never executed

```
 protected override void OnActivated (IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
   //Test Code
}
```

Comment: Is this running under the debugger?

Comment: yes is it running under debugger  rowland , but the vs dropdown does allow me to suspend , resume , suspend and terminate, how do i test the activated scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mix Resuming and Activation. In WP8.1 RT it works little different that in WP8.0. Please take a look at [App Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464925.aspx). There is a list in which cases your app is being activated. For example you will have *OnActivated* launched after *FileOpenPicker* but you won't get it fired after *Suspension* (then the *Resuming* event is fired).

You won't be able to test your *OnActivated* by using lifecycle event dropdown. To test it you will have to get it invoked (take a look at these lifecycle events at msdn), also open project properties, go to *Debug* and mark a tick *Do not launch, but debug my code when it starts*.

Please also remeber that your app can be terminated by the OS (for example due to lack of resources) while it's deactivated/suspended.